# Need an example for play2-elasticsearch module used with slick

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch, slick-2.0

I want to use https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch in my play project where I am using slick2.0 for database interactions. But unfortunately I can't find any proper documentation or example which could help me get started.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know well Slick, but I suppose that your data is represented as `case class` instances.

In this case, you can look at the Scala sample of the module, especially, the IndexTest class : https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch/blob/master/samples/elasticsearch-scala/app/indexing/IndexTest.scala . First, you will see that your `case class` needs to extend the `Indexable` trait. Then that you have to define an `IndexableManager` for your class that is used to specify the ES `type` to use and the Json `reads` and `writes` for converting your data (you can just use the `Json.reads` / `Json.writes` macro for a basic usage).

Then you can look at the sample controller that show the usage of the `IndexableManager` to index, delete and search indexed data : https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch/blob/master/samples/elasticsearch-scala/app/controllers/Application.scala